# Flutter Plugin with xcframework only works with device not in ios simulator

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I have created a flutter plugin.
By running the example app in Flutter I get this error:

```
Error: Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'AusweisApp2'
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|       
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.platform = :ios, '11.0'
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/AusweisApp2.xcframework'
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework AusweisApp2' }

  # Flutter.framework does not contain a i386 slice.
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386' }
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
end
```

The App works on device but not on ios simulators. You can download the xcframework here
https://github.com/Governikus/AusweisApp2-SDK-iOS

**Update:**

- In `Flutter 2.2.1` it works
- In `Flutter 2.5.3` it works not
- in `Flutter 2.8.0` it works
- in `Flutter 2.8.1` it works not
- in `Flutter 2.10.3` it works not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter/Xcode builds the app for the simulator in `arm64` and `x86_64` architecture for some reason. You can simply exclude the `arm64` architecture by adding this line to your `podspec`:

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386 arm64' }
```